.NET 6: Can't get access_token from http context in ActionFilterAttribute
I am using Scoruba IdentityServer (Scoruba IDP) for authentication in my ASP.NET Core 6 application. The following code works perfectly in my DEV/TEST environments, but it fails in the production environment. I've been searching for a solution for two days without success. Can anyone help me figure out what's going wrong?
Here is the relevant code:
C#
public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
{
    var accessToken = await context.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
    _logger.LogError("accessToken: " + accessToken);
    // additional logic
}

In production, GetTokenAsync doesn't return the expected token. I have verified that the authentication flow is working correctly and that the token is being issued.
Environment details:
DEV/TEST: ASP.NET Core 6
What I have tried:

Verified the token issuance and its presence in the request.
Checked the production configuration to ensure it matches the DEV/TEST environments.
Ensured that all required scopes and claims are included in the token.

Additional information:
There are no errors or exceptions thrown, but the accessToken variable is null in production.
Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance.
I also tried using IHttpContextAccessor from DI to get the token, but I got the same result

Do you use load balancing in your production environment? Is the authorization header configured on the web server?

Please use Fiddler to obtain http trace to analyze at which step Authorization is lost.
